# Filter by date anjularjs

Tags: ngtable

I am trying to filter by Date. The answer on this post worked for me by **boindiil**
[AngularJS ngTable filtering by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729542/angularjs-ngtable-filtering-by-date/26735685#26735685)

The only problem I am having is that the filter for the Date is Case sensitive. **How do I make it not to be case sensitive**? When you run his code and you type lowercase `j` or `f` for the date, no results are shown. You have to type exactly what it is. 
The Name filter is not case sensitive. you can type lowercase or uppercase it works.

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a check in your filter for lowercase as well.

Just replace

```
if($filter('date')(value.Date).indexOf(dateString) >= 0) {
  filtered.push(value);
}
```

with

```
var lower = $filter('date')(value.Date.toDateString().toLowerCase()).indexOf(dateString);
var normal = $filter('date')(value.Date).indexOf(dateString);

if(normal >= 0 || lower >= 0) {
  filtered.push(value);
}
```

Comment: it is throwing an error on this line var lower = $filter('date')(value.Date.toDateString().toLowerCase()).indexOf(dateString);                 it says toDateString is not a function  The value of my Date field is like this        "2015-02-09T20:06:33.163"

Comment: Check your spelling, also review this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString