# How to filter date in ngTable?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to filter date in ngTable based on the given format `d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735685/801116) and created a custom filter, but it does not take the given format instead `d MMM, yyyy`.

How can I have filter on ngTable to filter dates in a given format? Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nBclLmHTHrdm8lHl4Zcq?p=preview)

ngTable

```
<td data-title="'Start Date'" class="text-center" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'start_date': 'text' }" sortable="'type'">{{item.start_date| date: 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td data-title="'End Date'" class="text-center" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'end_date': 'text' }" sortable="'type'">{{item.end_date| date: 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
```

Custom filter

```
filter('customUserDateFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(values, dateString) {
        var filtered = [];
        if (typeof values != 'undefined' && typeof dateString != 'undefined') {
            angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
                var source = ($filter('date')(value.start_date)).toLowerCase();
                var temp = dateString.toLowerCase();
                //if ($filter('date')(value.start_date).indexOf(dateString) >= 0) {
                //if (temp.indexOf(" ") >=0)
                    //debugger;
                if (source.indexOf(temp) >= 0) {
                    filtered.push(value);
                }
            });
        }
        return filtered;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful when you are changing the format of the date. This is because the filter formats the date which has to be the same format as shown in the table to ensure correct functionality:

```
var source = ($filter('date')(value.start_date)).toLowerCase();
```

must be changed to this:

```
var source = ($filter('date')(value.start_date, 'd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')).toLowerCase();
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xjOdiuDhWUw3nSA5fQEQ?p=preview) is the working plunkr.